# How and which Beacon SDK to use?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon, estimote, eddystone

I am starting my app development using Xamarin and BLE technology.

What I want end of the day is able to use iOS and Android as beacon device to transmit and receive signals from app. And then when in near or proximity, app should detect that.

I searched and found key things are:
1. IOS: IBeacon, inbuilt in OS
2. Android:
2.a Altbeacon
2.b Estimote
2.c Eddystone

my questions are:
1. Any app or sample where using C# i can achieve BLE transmitter and receiver
2. Which SDK i should use in android to achieve the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iBeacon format on both Android and iOS.  The other formats work equally well on Android, but iBeacon has much faster and more reliable detections on iOS.

With Xamarin, you can use this project to bind to the Android Beacon Library:

https://github.com/chrisriesgo/Android-AltBeacon-Library

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. may i ask one thing. is it same as downloading from nuget package in VS. there are 2.7 which says only for BLE beacon and another is all beacon. does that means BLE beacon is supported in android and IOS both?

Comment: Both iBeacon and AltBeacon are specific types of BLE beacons.  BLE beacon is just a more general term to say it supports both.  Yes, downloading via nuget is fine.